# Web Deploy removing quotes in connection string

Tags: entity-framework, webdeploy

The last quote escape is being removed in the webserver web.config when using webdeploy.

Any ideas why?

I've currently having to log on to the server and readd it everytime I publish the site!

```
<add name="Entities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model.csdl|res://*/Model.ssdl|res://*/Model.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;server=server;database=db;user id=1;password=password;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework;&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

becomes:

```
 <add name="Entities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model.csdl|res://*/Model.ssdl|res://*/Model.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;server=server;database=db;user id=1;password=password;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove ";" (semicolon) before

> &quot

try this,

```
<add name="Entities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model.csdl|res://*/Model.ssdl|res://*/Model.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;server=server;database=db;user id=1;password=password;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Comment: Hi Sagar, at first glance it appeared to work but just realised it didn't fix the issue :(

Comment: Hi @churchley,I checked your connection string twice,it is perfect after removing ; before quot,there is chance of some mistake or unnecessary quot at your server or database,please recreate it.